# Swift class array with enum

Tags: arrays, swift, class, enums

I just read the Apple Documentation regarding `enum`s but I'm still somewhat confused.

Say I have the class named **Employee**. I want the class employee to have **an array of tasks** (I guess best option is [String]). But I want each task to have **a status** that's either `.Complete` or `.Incomplete`.

I could have another property inside `Tasks` called taskName, but I think it's easier to just make the `Array` store `String`s

Here's what I thought so far to write:

```
class Employee {
    class Tasks: Array { // Or [String], I have no idea
        enum Status {
            case Complete
            case Incomplete
        }
    }

    var tasks: Tasks

    init?() {
        self.tasks = Tasks()
    }
}

// Then I guess Employee.tasks[0].Status should work
```

I know that it's most likely wrong. So how should I do it?

Comment: You can check the link in documentation for Enumerations: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/224/enums/822/basic-enumerations#t=201607231049013737871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple way how you can do.

```
//Employee Class with Array of Task
class Employee {
    var tasks: [Task]
    init(tasks: [Task]) {
        self.tasks = tasks
    }
}

//Task Class has the status
class Task {
    var status:Status
    var taskName: String
    init(status: Status, taskName: String) {
        self.status = status
        self.taskName = taskName
    }
}

//Status is an enum
enum Status {
    case Complete
    case Incomplete
}
```

And here is the simple test code...

```
//Testing 
let task1 = Task(status: Status.Complete, taskName: "First Task")
let task2 = Task(status: Status.Incomplete, taskName: "Second Task")
let employee = Employee(tasks: [task1, task2])

print(employee.tasks[0].status) //Prints -->> Complete
print(employee.tasks[1].taskName)//Prints -->> Second Task
```

Comment: So if I also want a string with the task, all I need to do is add `var taskName: String` in `Task` and then I could access `employee.tasks[0].taskName`, right?

Comment: Yes you can do... I have edited the answer check out... @Lawrence413